# Why are the Scala libraries implemented with mutable state?

Tags: scala, immutability

Why are some methods in Scala's standard libraries implemented with mutable state?

For instance, the `find` method as part of `scala.Iterator` class is implemented as

```
def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  var res: Option[A] = None
  while (res.isEmpty && hasNext) {
    val e = next()
    if (p(e)) res = Some(e)
  }
  res
}
```

Which could have been implemented as a `@tailrec`'d method, perhaps something like

```
def findNew(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {

  @tailrec
  def findRec(e: A): Option[A] = {
    if (p(e)) Some(e)
    else {
      if (hasNext) findRec(next())
      else None
    }
  }

  if (hasNext) findRec(next())
  else None
}
```

Now I suppose one argument could be the use of mutable state and a `while` loop could be more efficient, which is understandably very important in library code, but is that really the case over a `@tailrec`'d method?

Comment: Your question seems to make the assumption that it would be better if these methods were immutable.  Is that the case?  Iterators are essentially state engines, after all.

Comment: From my (not extensive) experience, Scala and functional languages in general prefer immutability.

Comment: Well, Linq is immutable above the covers, but below the covers it uses `yield` `return`, which at its core is a mutable state engine, much like this one.  In Haskell, mutability is essentially hidden behind monad magic.  If you dig deep enough, I suspect you'll find mutability everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

There is no harm in having a mutable state as long as he is **not shared**.

In your example there is no way the mutable var could be accessed from outside, so it's not possible that this mutable variable change due to a side effect.

It's always good to enforce immutability as much as possible, but when performance matter there is nothing wrong in having some mutability as long as it's constrained in a safe way.

*NOTE: Iterator is a data-structure which is not side-effect free and this could lead to some weird behavior, but this is an other story and in no way the reason for designing a method in such way. You'll find method like that in immutable data-structure too.*

Answer (score 3):

In this case the `tailrec` quite possibly has the same performance as the `while` loop. I would say that in this case the `while` loop solution is shorter and more concise.

But, iterators are a mutable abstraction anyway, so the gain of having a tail recursive method to avoid that `var`, which is local to that short code snippet, is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is not designed for *functional purity* but for broadly useful capability.  Part of this includes trying to have the most efficient implementations of basic library routines (certainly not universally true, but it often is).

As such, if you have two possible interfaces:

```
trait Iterator[A] { def next: A }
trait FunctionalIterator[A] { def next: (A, FunctionalIterator[A]) }
```

and the second one is awkward and slower, it's quite sensible to choose the first.

When a functionally pure implementation is superior for the bulk of use cases, you'll typically find the functionally pure one.

And when it comes to simply using a `while` loop vs. recursion, either one is easy enough to maintain so it's really up to the preferences of the coder.  Note that `find` would have to be marked `final` in the `tailrec` case, so `while` preserves more flexibility:

```
trait Foo {
  def next: Int
  def foo: Int = {
    var a = next
    while (a < 0) a = next
    a
  }
}

defined trait Foo


trait Bar {
  def next: Int
  @tailrec def bar: Int = {
    val a = next
    if (a < 0) bar else a
  }
}

<console>:10: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method bar:
it is neither private nor final so can be overridden
             @tailrec def bar: Int = {
                          ^
```

There are ways to get around this (nested methods, final, redirect to private method, etc.), but it tends to adds boilerplate to the point where the `while` is syntactically more compact.

Comment: Tail recursion does NOT compromise flexibility, you can easily have a non final next method which call an other private final method which have the tailrec annotation `trait Foo { def bar(x: Int) = foo(x); @tailrec final def foo(x: Int): Int = foo(x - 1) }`

Comment: @AloisCochard - Well, sure, but you're adding even more boilerplate then.  (You probably want to make it private as well so your interface doesn't have two methods do the same thing.  Or you could make it an inner function.)

Comment: Sometimes it's good to be a bit more verbose if you can keep flexibility by doing so :-) ... of course in this specific case `while` is more concise, but always preferring `while` over tail-recursion just for this reason would be a shame.

Comment: @AloisCochard - They're of equivalent performance (with `while` being optimized a little more easily/rapidly in some contexts, but `tailrec` having slightly better warmed-up performance in some contexts) and are approximately equally easy to understand for someone well-versed in both styles of programming.  There isn't much left to prefer _except_ for conciseness/readability and dogma.  Given that choice, I'll pick conciseness/readability every time.  (This doesn't always resolve in favor of `while`, but I'll go whichever way it seems to lead.)

Comment: I totally agree, this is the approach I tend to use too.